# Denoise is missing in 2.79

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, denoise

I just downloaded the official release of 2.79, and I'm missing the Denoise feature in my Render properties.  Is there some step I'm missing in order to activate it?[image]

Comment: It's in the scene panel, not render.

Comment: Well that was a good 40 minutes wasted, wow I can't believe I missed it was on Render Layers, not Render.  Thanks for you rhelp @Mareck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [denoising controls](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html) for the **Cycles** render engine are in the Scene Panel:

[image]

Denoising is not available for blender internal

Just in case, for 2.8 the denoiser is in the view layer section of the dat properties editor:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean the Render Layers panel instead of the Scene Panel, inside the Properties panel. (I think you might have mistook the Scene "*Control*" for the Scene "*Context*", on what is actually the "*Render Layers Context*". This would be confirmed by the icons on your screenshot.)